# Не добавляется fab в layout файле

Tags: android, android-studio

Установил библиотеку FloatActionMenu, в build.gradle все нормально, добавил сам элемент на файл разметки, но тут проблема. Не указывается fab - характеристика, в инете ответа найти не смог, кто подскажет ?

![скрин] https://pp.userapi.com/c638531/v638531491/5541b/elrCe8RQyaQ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо указать пространство имён в вашем теге или в корневом. Т.е. добавить такую строку в атрибуты одно из тегов:

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Это можно сделать и с помощью `Alt+Enter`